# Connection reset by tomcat server on continuous reception of HTTP GET request

Tags: server, tomcat6, performance-testing, load-testing, tcp

I am doing load test of web server. Current i am using tomcat 6 to test my code. While running the server resets the connection after few minutes on receiving continuous GET requests for the same page. If I send GET request with some gap (say 500 ms) then it works fine. If I send GET request with 10 ms or less than 10 ms then server resets the connection after few seconds from the start of test. Please help on how to fix this problem. What is the reason for reset ? Whether the server is overloaded or I have to perform some operation while establish connection ??.

My GET request format is:

GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: 180.168.40.40
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: Running Env: 
Linux
Single core processor 
1 GB RAM

Comment: Check how many number of requests/threads are being used while its failing. And check if the number of threads is more than acceptCount(default is 100)

Comment: Ya I increased those parameters. If that is a problem means then it has to fail immediately. But for me it resets randomly after few minutes from the test start...

Comment: I configured threads = 10000, acceptCount=1000

Comment: What does the stacktrace say? and what I kind of application is this(index.html)

Comment: Reset occurs in Server side (tomcat). How can i stack trace ?. How to trace the reason for reset in third party server ?. I juz requesting the default page (index.html) of tomcat server. I observed one thing, that is if the download file size is 2 mb (pdf file) then the requests are pushed with some gap since after downloading full file the client has sent request. I assumed that the server resets connection on overload which implies the request rate it has received should be controlled. Is my assumption correct ? If I am wrong, Please correct me.

Comment: Got the solution :) Actually we have to configure the keep alive max requests to -1 in tomcat configuration.